# How can I combine two arrays of object in Mongodb Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am creating a mongodb aggregation pipeline, and basically I ended up having two arrays of object:

**services**:
`[ {"_id": "12345",  "name: "Name1", "type": "service" }, ...]`

and

**sections**:
`[ {"_id": "9875",  "name: "Name6", "type": "section" }, ...]`

Now I want to merge those two arrays together in a **data** array that would look like that:

`[ {"_id": "12345",  "name: "Name1", "type": "service" }, {"_id": "9875",  "name: "Name6", "type": "section" }, ...]`

I tried to make a $concatArrays but if I'm not wrong it is only working with simple arrays. I also tried to do:

`{ $addFields: { data: "$sections" } },`

`{ $addFields: { data: { $map: { input: "$services", as: "service", in: "$$service" } }`

But it's obviously replacing the previous **data** value by my **services**.
It seems really simple, but I can't figure out how could i do that.

Also, my mongodb is in 3.7 version.
Thanks ;)

Comment: `$concatArrays` is the way to go

Comment: I am not aware of a MongoDB version 3.7. However, it would be End-of-life anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$setUnion` in aggregation like the below example.

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "serviceAndSections": {
             $setUnion: ["$services", "$sectionssections"]
         }
    }
}
```

Visit this link it will help to understand `$setUnion` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/